# a method to remove UTF Bytes from memory?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a **c# application**, I have an important string in **byte[]** arrays...
I need to compute it only once time at start up of my application and then remove it **forever !**

Ok , Now I got a dump file and I found the string in its memory but I erased memory before!

**Before checking my code :**

> `byte[] bytearray_test` = **a text comes from internet as bytes ...**

Well , Methods I used to hide string from [dumpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and remove it after using it:

**A >** I deliver my string data using an **unmanaged library** as a bridge to the client, I set all of `SecureZeroMemory` , `ZeroMemory` and `RtlZeroMemory` in my c++ bridge , I tested a lot and it's working perfect . 
there is **no memory leak** , **no memory footprint** and **no string data** in memory dump.

c++ : **IT PASSED!**

**B >** after it I create a **new byte[] array** and I use Marshal.Copy to write IntPtr data to a byte[] array.

And after using it I erase it using invoked `RtlZeroMemory` from **Kernel32.dll**.

Okay ...

After step 1 & 2 I get a full dump from my debugger and I finally see there's nothing like my string inside and it works perfectly !

**

### But the problem is :

---

When I open dump file with **HxD** ( or every other hex editor)
I see the string as UTF16 sit in there :(
Image :
[IMAGE OF HxD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4cQF.jpg)

**What Can I do to hide it Hex Editor ?**

**My Idea :**

- Is there anyway to make a c# Application **patch** itself at **runtime ?**
  like find 10 hex value of current running .net application and change it at real time ??
- if you need any more information tell it to me , I'll send you the details

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you.

Comment: Note, that your byte[] array is a managed type. Unless it is large enough to go onto the "large object heap" (i guess the size threshold was 85000 bytes), it will be on the "small object heap". The CLR can move objects around in the small object heap -- which boils down to memory copy operations. However, if it moves an object in the heap, the original storage location for that object, while unused, still contains the byte data of the object (unless it is used and overwritten by something else)

Comment: Either don't use a managed type for your sensitive data, or pin the array in memory before filling it. But it is really not that secure in itself. Your program still handles the data, and an enterprising soul with the knowledge to dump memory can also intercept your program at opportune times (or monitor data that goes in and out of your program) to get a pretty clear understanding of what the data is you so desperately try to hide...

Comment: It shouldn’t be in memory if you store it in a value type as  elgonzo was suggesting, right? So maybe if you store each letter into one large floating point number assigned to a global variable and made up of a list of characters in the string.. each character can be a 2 digit number based on the position in alphabet eg a=01 , b=02, etc.. so it will look like 0.021201270212012702120127 which means bla bla bla..

Comment: @numbtongue Floating point numbers only have so much precision. That's a number that can't be stored. The maximum is probably `0.021201270212012704` and the last bit is subject to rounding.

Comment: Or a struct with 10 floating point numbers..

Comment: @AlanBirtles this question is about helping writing a method not really bug or something ... thanks

Comment: @elgonzo can I offset a byte array and then turn it back at runtime without storing in memory ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "_offset a byte array_", and i also don't know what you mean when you are saying "_turn it back at runtime without storing in memory_". Please clarify.

Comment: @elgonzo it's simple , you have word "Hello!" , it's 48 65 6C 6C 6F 21 in hex and 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x21 in byte[] array so there are numbers and we can change the value , now for offset i mean , add 2 to each value in undamaged and return the bytes in C# and store it in application

Comment: You know already how P/Invoke marshalling works, according to the information in your question. So what specifically is the problem here with getting an unmanaged byte[] returned back to C#? (Again, i want to emphasize that what you are trying to do does not give you a net benefit in security/protection. That also means i do not want to much discuss things that basically will not provide a real benefit...)

Comment: If you really want to handle confidental data in a somewhat secure way, you will have rely on the "protection services" of the OS (such as Microsoft's MCAPI, for example), or, much better, protection by some dedicated hardware module that provides security-related functions. Either of which is far too large and too advanced a topic for discussing it here in the comments...

Comment: (Oops, small but perhaps important typo: It is not MCAPI, but MSCAPI or MSCAPI/CNG. Sorry...)

Comment: @elgonzo thanks , I found a way to doing it and perfectly there is no more footprint ... I used custom secure string and an modified encoder

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to store your data in a [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=netframework-4.7.2). That's not foolproof though, if your attacker has admin privileges on your machine to get access to your memory, there is not much you can do but delay.

Comment: nope , I don't want to use secure string , it has really low secuirty